# Why I can not calculate double value?

Tags: java, double, double-precision

I want to calculate the value 0.95. Here is my method:

```
public static final int VAR = 5; 
private static double getDouble(){
        double dis = (double)(VAR/100);
        dis = (double)(1-dis);
        return dis;
}
```

However, it output 1.0?? If I type the same code in main method I got 0.95. Where is my mistake?

Comment: The result of an integer division will always be an integer. In your case,  your integer is then being converted to a double, doing at @kocko recommends should fix the problem.

Comment: what is the datatype of `VAR`

Answer (score 6):

`(5/100)` will return `0`, which will be casted to `double` as `0.0`.

Just do:

```
double dis = (5d/100);
```

Since you have declared `VAR = 5`, you have to cast it to `double` and then do the division:

```
double dis = ((double) VAR) / 100;
```

Comment: Thanks! What is I have declared 5 as final static int in the code? I will update the actual code.